# How can I pack a string in struct.pack

Tags: python

I am trying to pack a string using struct.pack.
I am able to see complete value if I use integer type but when I want to use string I only see one character.

```
struct.pack("<1L",0xabcdabcd)
'\xab\xcd\ab\cd'
struct.pack("<1s","overflow")
'o' prints just s. I wanted it to print full string: overflow.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the format string (`"<1s"`) you're passing to `struct.pack`, the 1 denotes the maximum number of characters that field can store. (See the paragraph beginning "For the `'s'`..." in [the `struct` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters).) Since you're passing 1, it will only store the first character. You'll need to choose a length that will fit any string you want to store in the struct, and specify that. For example, to store the string "overflow" (8 characters) you could use `"<8s"`:

```
>>> struct.pack("<8s", "overflow")
'overflow'
```

Comment: Did this answer solve your problem? If so, please accept it.